# Error:The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details

Tags: android, ionic-framework, mobile

I'm trying to run an application with the ionic serve command, but the following error is displayed:

```
$ ionic serve
> ng run app:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
[ng] The specified command run is invalid. For available options, see `ng help`.

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

I already have the nodeJs (version 8.8.1), ionic (version 4.10.2), and cordova (version 8.1.2) installed

What can it be?

Answer (score 1):

The nodeJs version 8.8.1 is not compatible with ionic.

Install node latest stable version (10.9 or greater):

```
sudo n stable
```

then run `ionic serve` again.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```